# Lookup a value in the same row and return value from a column next to the matching column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet laid out as follows, with two formulas:

```
      A     B     C         D
  +-------+---+-------+-----------+
1 | 164F  | 1 | 164F  | formula 1 |
  +-------+---+-------+-----------+
2 | 1638  | 4 | 1638  | formula 2 |
  +-------+---+-------+-----------+
```

I want the formula 1 to look at the value in the column C and return the value from the right column referent to the value seen, like if the value of column C is 164F, it will search the row for the left and return the value in column B =1, value which is at the right of the value looked. I'm working on a table for referencing. I have provided an example [on this Excel forum](http://www.excelforum.com/newthread.php?do=postthread&f=8).

Comment: So you link to an example where you need an account to access the content?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Which program are you using?  What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Is there any way of modifying the ascii art directly after "My Problem:" to make it more understandable?

Answer (score 3):

This is solved with an `=Index(Match())` formula. It works a bit like a `Vlookup`

```
=INDEX(B1:B10, MATCH('164F', C1:C10, 0), 1)
```

This will search column C for '164F' and will return the corresponding value in Column B